# Differentiate $\arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function, chain-rule

This is from Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd Edition, Chapter 15, problem 1 (iv):

> Differentiate $f(x) = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right).$

Here's my attempt:
\begin{align}f'(x) &= \left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)\right]' \\
&= \arcsin'\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)' \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)^2}} \cdot \frac{-x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}}} \cdot \frac{-x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2 - 1}{1+x^2}}} \cdot \frac{-x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}} \\
&= \frac{-x}{\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \cdot \sqrt{1 + x^2}(1+x^2)} \\
&=\frac{-x}{|x|} \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}.\end{align}

Therefore
$$f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{-1}{1+x^2},  & \text{if $x > 0$} \\[1ex]
\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}, & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

In the Answer Book the published solution is $\frac{-1}{1+x^2}$.

It seems Spivak is discounting the possibility that $x < 0$. Why might this be? Is there a reason $x$ cannot be negative here? Did I make a mistake? Perhaps with this part of simplifying the denominator?

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}} \cdot \sqrt{1 + x^2} = \sqrt {x^2} = |x|$$

I suspect there's something simple I'm not seeing. I'm just now encountering these inverse trigonometric functions, so my understanding isn't very solid yet.

**Edit:** This error could have become a misleading, possibly demoralizing waste of time, but thanks your insightful answers it's instead proven to be more instructive than the first 3 (omitted, correct) parts of the problem.

Comment: A simple way to detect that Spivak is wrong is to note that $f(-x)=f(x)$, so $f(x)$ is an even function. But that means that $f'(x)$ must be odd, which $-1/(1+x^2)$ is not. (By contrast, your function is indeed odd.) In particular, if $f'(x)$ existed everywhere (as Spivak seems to do) one would have $f'(0)=0$ not $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Very good explanations! I wish I could upvote it as an answer unfortunately it is a comment:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us verify in another way:

Let $y=\arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\implies\dfrac\pi2\ge y\ge0$

and $x^2=\csc^2y-1$

If $x\ge0, y=\text{arccot}x=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan x$

If $x<0, x=-\cot y, $

Consequently, $y=\cdots=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(-x)=\dfrac\pi2+\arctan x$

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is fine, and it appears that the Answer Book (assuming that you are quoting it correctly—I don't have access to that book) is incorrect (or, at least, omitting a hypothesis or restriction of some sort).  That being said, the real issue here is not that the solutions manual is wrong, but that you lack confidence in your work, or lack the resources to reassure yourself that what you have done is correct.

This is fine!

Lacking confidence is a part of learning.  However, another part of learning is figuring out how to acquire confidence in your own work, and what kind of resources might help.  So, rather than commenting on the particular problem that you are facing, allow me to address the larger question:  if I believe that at a text is wrong, what can I do?

1. First and foremost, reread the text.  Then reread it again.  Make sure that you are not missing any important definitions or ideas.  In this case, I would wonder about the domain of the function being considered, and how Spivak treats the derivative of a function which is not differentiable on its domain.

   In this case, the function you are differentiating is not differentiable at zero.  It might be reasonable to conclude that Spivak is only giving the derivative on some domain where the function *is* differentiable, e.g. on $(0,\infty)$.  You might look back at earlier chapters and see if this might provide an explanation.

   Of course, if this is the case, I would argue that Spivak is being a little sloppy, but pobody's nerfect.
2. Look for a list of errata (an *erratum* is an error made up to the time of printing, such as a typographical error).  When mistakes or errors are made in texts—particularly technical texts such as mathematics or physics books—the author or publisher (or an interested third party) may keep and publish a list of errata.  If you think that there is an error in the text, try looking for such a list.

   For example, the [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spivak+calculus+third+edition+errata) `spivak calculus third edition errata` may bring up some useful results.  None of the first page of results looks overly promising, but your milage may vary.
3. Look for alternative ways of understanding the problem and/or verifying that your solution is correct.  If you are trying to find an antiderivative, try differentiating to check your work.  Use a CAS (computer algebra system) to check your solution.  Look for patterns or symmetries which might help you determine whether you are right or wrong.

   In this case, the function
   $$ x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$
   is even.  It is not terribly difficult to verify that the composition of *any* function with an even function is again even, and so
   $$x \mapsto \arcsin\!\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \right) $$
   must also be even.  A useful fact about even functions is that their derivatives are odd, hence the expectation is that the result here should be an odd function.  Spivak's solution is not odd, while yours is.  This should give you some confidence (at the very least, you know that Spivak has been unclear or made an error).

   Another possibility is to use some technology to build confidence.  For example, GeoGebra can be used to graph Spivak's function, compute derivatives, and so on.  [A graph of GeoGebra's derivative and your own](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/xgeumyr2) should be convincing.  Again, this is not proof that you are right, but should help you to have confidence in your result.

Comment: Great tips Xander, but you left one out: consulting with the good folks of MSE. Y'all haven't just helped me get over an obstacle: the rope's still there for the next person that runs into this problem.

Comment: @Ben Sure.  I could also have said "Go talk to your prof."  However, the goal is to build a toolset which allows you to be comfortable with your own work, so that you *don't* have to ask another person.  I'm not saying that you should never ask for help (in fact, you should ask for help all the time---learning is collaborative), but if you can be confident in your own work, then you don't have to rely on "experts" (who make mistakes, and can be wrong).

Comment: I'm glad you didn't say that; my prof right now is Spivak circa 1994. I like the idea of leaving some breadcrumbs for anyone else foolish enough to be trying to make their way through this outdated edition. It's a great book, but also full of errors. Most are simple typos, but some are more serious. For the latter type I've gotten into the habit of checking MSE to see if anyone else has found the same thing. Perhaps this is not the intended purpose, but I reckon some small portion of MSE serves as a defacto errata list for abandoned classics.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$f(\sinh(x))=\arcsin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}})=\arcsin(\frac{1}{\cosh(x)})$$

The differentiation gives

$$f'(\sinh(x))\cosh(x)=$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}}}\frac{-\sinh(x)}{\cosh^2(x)}=$$

$$\frac{-1}{\cosh(x)}\frac{\sinh(x)}{|\sinh(x)|}$$

$$\implies f'(\sinh(x))=\frac{\pm 1}{\cosh^2(x)}=\frac{-sign(x)}{1+\sinh^2(x)}$$

So,
$$f'(X)=\frac{-sign(X)}{1+X^2}$$